# Relationship between Weierstrass Theorem and Bernstein Polynomials?

Tags: real-analysis

I was reading about the Stone-Weierstrass Theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem) which talks about how there exists a polynomial that can approximate any function over any range and to some error "epsilon" - however, when looking at the proof of this theorem, it seems to be often done using Bernstein Polynomials (http://nonagon.org/ExLibris/bernstein-proves-weierstrass).

- Did Weierstrass provide a proof to this theorem prior to Bernstein? (It seems like he did using the Weierstrass Transform : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_transform)
- Why are the Bernstein Polynomials so important in the proof of the Weierstrass Theorem, if Weierstrass was able to prove this theorem without Bernstein Polynomials?

Thank you!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stigler%27s_law_of_eponymy

Comment: Thank you! I never knew that this law had a name!